# is_valid() method not work with my form in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-forms

I'm a beginner with Django 4.1. I'm using the model to edit a form and render it on a webpage. This runs correctly. When I click on submit, my function recognizes the *POST* method but never validates the form. I'm sure that I have to fix a bug in my models or my form but I don't know where.

in ***models.py***:

```py
class Auction(models.Model):
    HOUSE = "HOU"
    MOTORS = "MOT"
    PROPERTY = "PPT"
    HOBBIES = "HOB"
    INFORMATION_TECHNOLOGY = "IT"
    MUSIC = "MUS"
    BOOK = "BOK"

    CATEGORY_CHOICES = [
        (HOUSE, "All for your House"),
        (MOTORS, "Car, Moto, Boat"),
        (PROPERTY, "Houses, flats, manors"),
        (HOBBIES, "Hobbies"),
        (INFORMATION_TECHNOLOGY, "Laptop, Desktop, Mobile Phone"),
        (MUSIC, "CD, Musical Intrusments"),
        (BOOK, "Books, Comics,...")
    ]


    ONE = 1
    THREE = 3
    SEVEN = 7
    FOURTEEN = 14

    DURATION_CHOICES = [
        (ONE, "1 day"),
        (THREE, "3 days"),
        (SEVEN, "7 days"),
        (FOURTEEN, "14 days")
    ]

    title = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    image = models.URLField(null=True, blank=True, default="")
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="seller")
    duration = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=DURATION_CHOICES, default=SEVEN)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=3, choices=CATEGORY_CHOICES, default=INFORMATION_TECHNOLOGY)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2, default=0.0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.id}: {self.title}"
```

in ***forms.py***:

```py
class CreateListingsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Auction
        fields = ["title", "description", "image", "category", "duration", "price"]
```

and in ***views.py***:

```py
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateListingsForm(request.POST)
        form.instance.user = request.user
        form.instance.creation_date = datetime.now()
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listings.html", {
            "form": form
            })
    else:
        form = CreateListingsForm()
        return render(request, "auctions/listings.html", {
            "form": form
        })
```

I've tried to handle instances like below. I've tried to override `__init__` in my form too.

Edit:
I do `print(form.error)` and the result is:

```
<ul class="errorlist"><li>duration<ul class="errorlist"><li>Select a valid choice. 7 is not one of the available choices.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

May the problem be my default value?

Edit2:

The error was the type of the field so it works when I changed it to `IntegerField`.

Comment: Share your `listings.html` file.

Comment: I'm just guessing, but I think `ONE` `THREE` etc. have to be strings, not integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you don't have `"user"` and `"creation_date"` in your fields list (`["title", "description", "image", "category", "duration", "price"]`), so your form will be still invalid.

Try this:

```py
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateListingsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            listing = form.save(commit=false)
            listing.user_id = request.user.pk
            listing.create_date = datetime.now()
            listing.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else: # I think this else block is not so necessary
            return render(request, "auctions/listings.html", {
            "form": form
            })
    else:
        form = CreateListingsForm()
        return render(request, "auctions/listings.html", {
        "form": form
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
duration = models.CharField(max_length=7, choices=DURATION_CHOICES, default=SEVEN)
```

`max_length` and `min_length`: if provided, these arguments ensure that the string is at most or at least the given length.

I don't think you are checking if int has max value less than or equal to 7 so that's what is failing your validation. You will need to change that and perhaps add a validation rule in your form or change from `CharField` to a numeric field.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can try this:

```
def create(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateListingsForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           form.instance.user = request.user
           form.instance.creation_date = datetime.now()
           form.save()
           return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request, "auctions/listings.html", {
            "form": form
            })
    else:
        form = CreateListingsForm()
    return render(request, "auctions/listings.html", {
            "form": form
        })
```